# In the Aggregator module, limit number of items per feed

Tags: views, 8, feeds

I am using the Aggregator module in Drupal 8 to combine several RSS feeds, but I would like to set a limit on the number of items that are shown from any one feed. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the right way to do it but I solved this by using `template_preprocess_aggregator_feed(&$variables)` and then slice the items using `array_slice()`.

My items were stored at `$variables['content']['items']` but there were two other *hashtag variables* stored in the beginning of the array so I had to add that to the total count.

```
function template_preprocess_aggregator_feed(&$variables) {
  $number_of_items = 5;
  $variables['content']['items'] = array_slice($variables['content']['items'],0,2 + $number_of_items);
}
```